# Estimating PostgreSQL Table Size in GB for Varying Column Count and Row Quantity

Tags: database, postgresql

I need to estimate the size in GB of a table in a PostgreSQL database. I don't have the database yet (I need the estimate for cost projection purposes).

The schema of the table will be:

- One column containing a timestamp of when the record was created
- K other columns, all float numbers

K can be anywhere between 10 and 10000.

Is there a formula to estimate how big the table will be in GB, as a function of K and of the number of rows?

Comment: PostgreSQL has support for a maximum of 1600 columns, depending on the data type. But when you have so many columns, you most likely have a huge problem in your data model. Advice: First get your data model right, then start making an estimate of the size. And storage is cheap, why bother?

Comment: PostgreSQL has a limit of 1600 columns per table and a row size limit of 8160 bytes. Given the size of timestamps, floats, and additional overhead, this would allow a maximum of 1016 float columns if all of the columns have non-NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

a tiemstamp needs 8 bytes

A real 4 Bytes

So you have 8+ K * 4 bytes of raw data

lets say for 10

```
   23   -- heaptupleheader
 +  1   -- padding or NULL bitmap
 + 40   -- 10 * ireal
 +  8   -- padding after 10th real
 +  8   -- timestamp
 +  0   -- no padding since tuple ends at multiple of MAXALIGN
 +  4   -- item identifier in page header
------
 = 84 bytes for every row
```

which are 8.400000000000001e-8 Gigabyte, now you need to estimate the rows you have per month or year and multiply it

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use this formula:

> Estimated Table Size (in bytes) = (Number of Rows) * (Size of
> Timestamp Column + (K * Size of Float Column))

In PostgreSQL, the size of timestamp data type is generally 8 bytes. Float is 4 bytes.
This formula however does not factor in null values, padding, alignment, compression, or indexing which could increase the size.

You could also use the **pg_total_relation_size** function in PostgreSQL. You provide the function with the table's name and it gives you the size of the table, including indexes and associated objects.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this formula to estimate the table size:

> Estimated Table Size (GB) = (Row Size in Bytes + Index Size in Bytes) * Number of Rows / (1024^3)